# Twitter Api detect my tweet retweeted or favourited

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

Is it possible to detect that someone retweeted or favourited my status?
Does twitter api provide any listeners for a user's tweet RTd or Favourited?

In particular, I am looking for something with twitter4j that allows me to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok After thoroughly searching about Twitter Streaming Api, here is the code I have used:

For Favorite, I used `UserStreamListener` for listening for tweets of authenticating user favorited by other people(see `onFavorite()`):

```
        TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(new ConfigurationBuilder().setJSONStoreEnabled(true).build()).getInstance();

        twitterStream.setOAuthConsumer(StaticConstants.API_KEY, StaticConstants.API_SECRET);
        AccessToken token = new AccessToken(StaticConstants.TOKEN_KEY, StaticConstants.TOKEN_SECRET);
        twitterStream.setOAuthAccessToken(token);

        UserStreamListener listener = new UserStreamListener() {
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                System.out.println("Status: " + status.getText());
                //do your action here
            }

            @Override
            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice sdn) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int i) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrubGeo(long l, long l1) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning sw) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onException(Exception excptn) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onDeletionNotice(long l, long l1) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFriendList(long[] longs) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFavorite(User user, User user1, Status status) {
                System.out.println("User:"+user.getScreenName());
                System.out.println("User1 :"+user1.getScreenName());
                System.out.println("Status: "+status.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnfavorite(User user, User user1, Status status) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFollow(User user, User user1) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onDirectMessage(DirectMessage dm) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onUserListMemberAddition(User user, User user1, UserList ul) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onUserListMemberDeletion(User user, User user1, UserList ul) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onUserListSubscription(User user, User user1, UserList ul) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onUserListUnsubscription(User user, User user1, UserList ul) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onUserListCreation(User user, UserList ul) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onUserListUpdate(User user, UserList ul) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onUserListDeletion(User user, UserList ul) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onUserProfileUpdate(User user) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onBlock(User user, User user1) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onUnblock(User user, User user1) {
            }

        };
        twitterStream.addListener(listener);
        twitterStream.user();
```

For listening to retweets retweeted by other users for a particular user(not necessarily the authenticating user), I used `StatusListener` as follows:

```
          StatusListener statusListner=new StatusListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStatus(Status status) {
                System.out.println("Status Recvd: "+status.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice sdn) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int i) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrubGeo(long l, long l1) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void onStallWarning(StallWarning sw) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }

            @Override
            public void onException(Exception excptn) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        };

        TwitterStream twitterStream2 = new TwitterStreamFactory(new ConfigurationBuilder().setJSONStoreEnabled(true).build()).getInstance();

        twitterStream2.setOAuthConsumer(StaticConstants.API_KEY, StaticConstants.API_SECRET);
        AccessToken token2 = new AccessToken(StaticConstants.TOKEN_KEY, StaticConstants.TOKEN_SECRET);
        twitterStream2.setOAuthAccessToken(token2);

        twitterStream2.addListener(statusListner);
        FilterQuery query = new FilterQuery();
        query.follow(new long[]{12384567l});
        twitterStream2.filter(query);
```

Here the user id of user whose tweets we have to listen to for being retweeted by others(not necessarily followers), is being passed as parameter in `query.follow()`.
This works perfectly fine for me and is the recommended way for doing so. Its by no means a hack. I am sure that it would help others who have searched the net for a similar topic and would answer many similar unanswered questions on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but there is a caveat - this is an undocumented and unsupported API call

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/activity/about_me.json
```

You can only make a successful call to that resource if it is signed with the API keys of the **official** Twitter client.  i.e. Twitter for iPhone / Android / etc.

How you get those keys is left as an exercise in creativity.  Use of such undocumented APIs is prohibited by Twitter.  Use of someone else's keys is also prohibited.

Comment: Thats synonymous to saying its not possible this way :)

Comment: It's possible to find the API keys - they're out there :-)

Comment: Oh my! can u give me where is the link? I searched for it, but could not find. Its unbelievable that you can find api keys and secrets like that for any application!!!

Comment: Use The Force, Rahul :-)

Comment: Finally found the recommended way to do so.